# Are nets and filters useful in geometry and topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ultrafilters, nets

Many results in topology can be restated using the concepts of nets and ultrafilters. This seems to be of interest for set theorists, maybe even logicians. But for geometers and topologists, those who use point-set topology only as a tool in proving theorems about manifolds, varieties, schemes, homology groups, etc, can this reformulation be useful? If it is, please give examples of how it might be used.

In the case of Tychonoff's Theorem, it may provide an interesting way to prove a result in point-set topology which is useful for geometers, but even in this case, its use does not seem to shed much insight once one has obtained the technical point-set result.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, was the exclusion of (functional) analysis from your question deliberate? I ask in light of your responses to Henno Brandsma's answer.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that people doing point-set topology are topologists too. 

Comment: there are examples of compact hausdorff topological space with a sequence which does not have a convergent subsequence. so a subnet of this sequence can not be considered as a subsequence. Now a question:Assume that X is a compact Hausdorff topological space such that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Does it implies that X is first countable?

Comment: @AliTaghavi If Martin's axiom holds, then every product of $< 2^{\aleph_0}$ sequentially compact spaces is sequentially compact. So if the continuum hypothesis is false but Martin's axiom holds, then $2^{\aleph_1}$, with the product topology, is compact, Hausdorff, every sequence has a convergent subsequence, but is not first countable. There may well be a ZFC example, but I don't know one off the top of my head.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Actually, that was needlessly complicated. Let $X$ be an uncountable set, considered as a discrete space, and $Y$ it's one-point compactification. Then $Y$ is not first countable (at the new point because $X$ is not countable), but is compact, Hausdorff and every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @RobertFurber  Thank you very much  for your 2 interesting  comments. BTW may be some other examples can be  constructed in the unit ball of  some  appropriate reflexive Banach space the unit ball is compact and  sequentially compact but not necessarilly first countable space.

Answer (score 19):

I think the net formulation is quite useful to know, at least. Analysts seem to be most fond of it, as they naturally work with sequences anyway. E.g. on easily shows that the closure of a subgroup $H$ in a topological group $G$ is a subgroup: just note that for $x,y$ in closure of $H$, we find nets (wlog with the same index set) $(x_i), (y_i)$ from $H$ that converge to $x$, resp. $y$, and then $x_i \cdot {y_i}^{-1} \rightarrow x \cdot y^{-1}$ from continuity of the group operations, and the left hand side lives in $H$, so the right hand side is in closure H, and this is thus a subgroup.

Similarly, $A \cdot B$ is closed in $G$ when $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact: take a net $(x_i \cdot y_i)_{i \in I}$ in $A \cdot B$ converging to $z$. By compactness the net $(y_i)$ has a subnet converging to $y \in B$, indexed by $J$ say, and then the corresponding subnet $x_j = x_j \cdot y_j \cdot y_j^{-1}$ converges to $z \cdot y^{-1}$ and as the $(x_j)$ are in $A$, so is the limit $z \cdot y^{-1}$ and so $z = (z \cdot y^{-1} \cdot y)$ is in $A \cdot B$, making it closed.

Nets also make for a nice formulation of the Riemann integral (using partitions on the interval as a directed set under refinement) as a limit of a certain net. Some proofs just look more "natural" in a net formulation, I think. One can do the proof for sequences first, and see how it generalizes using nets.

Comment: Interesting. Now is it just a useful tool to make a few lemmas easier to prove (like the ones outlined)? Are there deep results which use the net/ultrafilter formulation?

Comment: This sort of thing, in some sense, comes down to "taste": sure, any proof using nets can be reformulated using "bare hands" topology (i.e. open sets, inverse images etc.) but really this is just a formal process.  I happen to think that nets make proofs _a lot_ easier to follow, which leads to a better intuition, which in turn perhaps leads to new proofs which would have been impossible to see without the simplifications which nets provided.

Comment: Interesting. Might anyone suggest that topology should be taught by introducing nets at the beginning? (i.e. reform the way that topology is taught)

Comment: The problem is that one of the axioms for a topology defined by nets, the diagonalization axiom or some such, is quite ugly and not too easy to work with (see Willard's book _General Topology_). However, I think it would be reasonable to define nets early on, and prove the sorts of theorems that are found in Munkres, Supplementary Exercises to Chapter 3 (leading up to "a space is compact iff every net has a convergent subnet).

Comment: The notion of subnet being subtler than that of subsequence could be one obstacle, perhaps. On the other hand, the book of Beardon mentioned by Michael Greinecker (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32035/are-nets-and-filters-useful-in-geometry-and-topology/32053#32053 ) might represent a step in the direction you suggest.

Comment: I think nets are horrendous to use. Try proving Tychonoff Theorem using nets: it is just painful. When you use ultrafilters it is a much nicer proof.

Comment: @alephomega: sometimes ultrafilters are cleaner; sometimes nets are more convenient or more intuitive (approximation arguments in biduals of Banach spaces or algebras, for instance). It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RachidAtmai: Hmm, I'm twelve and a half years late to the party - but as this just popped up at the front page again, I'd like to mention that proving Tychonoff's Theorem using nets is just as easy as the ultrafilter proof: one just needs the concept of *universal nets*, which is the "net analogue" of ultrafilters and can be used to characterize compactness in a similar way: a topological space is compact iff every universal net converges. As an analyst, I'm inclined to add that, once one has this, many compactness results in functional analysis become almost obvious.

Answer (score 16):

One of the most important constructions in geometric group theory is the asymptotic cone of a group or metric space, which captures what happens to the group or metric space as you rescale the metric down to zero (or, less formally, as you squint your eyes and move farther and farther away from the space).  The originated in Gromov's original proof of his  [polynomial growth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth), where the polynomial growth condition assures that this limit exists in the classical sense.  However, since then this concept has been hugely important in more general situations where one has to use an ultrafilter to define an appropriate notion of convergence.  I recommend perusing the wikipedia articles on
[Gromov-Hausdorff convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence) and [ultralimits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit).

Answer (score 10):

Nets (and also filters) allow one to unify the wide morass of convergence notions. There is even an undergraduate introduction to analysis based on nets, [Limits](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387982744) by Alan Beardon.

Notions like the convergence of sets (the liminf and limsup of sets stuff) can be formulated as a nontopological form of order convergence based on nets. These notions play an important part in general measure theory and especially in probability theory.

Kolmogorov's extension theorem of stochastic processes has abstract generalizations based on nets of $\sigma$-algebras. See for example [here](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/Notes/Kolmogorov.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112064810/http://www.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/Notes/Kolmogorov.pdf)).

Ultrafilters play a surprising role in social choice theory. The family of "pivotal sets of voters" implied by a social decision rule satisfying the assumption of [Arrow's impossibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) forms an ultrafilter, which explains why all such rules are dictatorial with finitely many voters but not in the case of infinitely many voters.

For an actual application of ultrafilters in geometry, see [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/30/the-ultralimit-argument-and-quantitative-algebraic-geometry/argument-and-quantitative-algebraic-geometry/) post on Terry Tao's blog.

Answer (score 9):

A few years ago de Fernex and Mustata used ultrafilters to prove some results on log canonical thresholds related to Shokurov's ACC conjecture.  See [deFernexMustata07](https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0710/0710.4978v4.pdf).

However, shortly after, Koll'ar proved the same results using more geometric methods, see [Kollar08](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0756) (making this a non-example in some people's mind).

I probably should also mention the work of Hans Schoutens using ultra filters to construct ultra-Frobenius (Frobenius in characteristic zero) and thus detect various types of singularities in characteristic zero.

Answer (score 8):

If a topological space is not first countable sequences can not be used for instance to verify the continuity of the function. In that case you can use nets instead. Topological spaces which are not first countable are commonly encountered in Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is the type of answer you are looking for, but, representing topological spaces by their ultrafilter convergence relation is quite useful for determining which topological spaces are exponentiable.

Comment: I'll bite: what's an exponentiable topological space?

Comment: google: http://eom.springer.de/e/e036940.htm

Comment: Oh, sorry, an exponentiable space is a space $X$ such that a mapping space (with the correct universal property!) $Y^X$ exists for every topological space $Y$. In other words, the functor $(blank) \times X:Top \to Top$ has a right-adjoint.

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/71866) above is broken, but the article can be found at [Exponential topology - Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Exponential_topology).

Answer (score 4):

Nets were first expounded by Moore and Smith in order to explain the convergence involved in the definition of the Riemann integral.  Would you say that is of no use in geometry and topology?

Comment: Yes,since the Riemann integral is an analytical construction in finite dimensional Euclidean spaces. But if that was thier sole use in mathematics,they would still be a VERY significant construction,don't you think? 

Comment: Nets were NOT initially expounded by Moore and Smith, but by L. Vietoris who anticipated them by a couple of years and in greater generality in his dissertation „Stetige Mangen“ which was published in Monatsheft. Math. in 1919 (available online) and in which he was the first to introduce the modern notion of compactness, rather than sequential compactness.  Even more remarkably he simultaneously introduced and studied the concept of a filter, thus anticipating Cartan and Bourbaki by nearly two decades. Of course he used his own german language terminology which never caught on.

Comment: The title of Vietoris' article is ,,Stetige Mengen'' (continuous sets).

Answer (score 4):

Those in functional analysis should read the book Beattie R, Butzmann H P : Convergence Structures and Applications to Functional Analysis. Kluwer, Dordrecht, 2002, and see how incredibly useful is to get beyond the Hausdorff-Kuratowski-Bourbaki topology, that is, the usual topology. And the issue is not whether one uses sequences, nets, filters, or whatever else. No the issue is simply how one uses them. And with the rather slight relaxation of the concept of usual topology in the above book, one can do miracles. Among them, the duality theory of locally convex vector spaces becomes so clear and simple.

Comment: would it really be so difficult to use the phrase "the usual notion of topology" rather than "the usual topology". The two mean different things.

Answer (score 4):

In formalised mathematics, Lean's [mathlib library](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/) uses filters extensively when developing the [basic theory of topological spaces](https://leanprover-community.github.io/theories/topology.html).  I do not know exactly why that decision was taken.  However, when a non-traditional formulation turns out to be more convenient for formalisation, it is often worth asking whether that formulation has advantages in other contexts as well.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly ultra-filters were used to prove Tychonoff's Theorem in Willards' General Topology book.

Answer (score 3):

Although this isn't geometry or topology, [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24047/ultrafilters-and-automorphisms-of-the-complex-field) gives an application of ultrafilters to field theory. I think this still counts as an application of ultrafilters outside of the fields in which they might normally appear.