# Automorphism groups of the complex numbers, and other fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields, axiom-of-choice, automorphism-groups

If one accepts the Axiom of Choice (AC), then the automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}$ is a huge and wild group, very poorly understood.

But apparently  if one does *not* accept the Axiom of Choice, then the automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}$ has size $2$, only consisting of the identity and complex conjugation. I should be more precise here (see the comments below): it is *consistent* with this assumption that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}$ has size $2$ (i. e., we can find models of ZF without AC in which this group has size $2$).

What are other interesting (classes of) fields where similar things can be said about the automorphism group ? (That is, upon not accepting the Axiom of Choice, one ends up with consistency of an "easy" or even trivial automorphism group.)

Comment: How are you going to prove that $\mathbb C$ has no more than two automorphisms?

Comment: Not accepting AC is not nearly enough. You're saying "Here is a finite set; I do not accept the claim it is empty. Therefore, it has exactly 4 elements".

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It is *consistent* with ZF that every automorphism of a Polish group is continuous, in that case only the identity and conjugations are automorphisms of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the explanation. So the correct statement is something like "In some model of ZF (without C) there are exactly two automorphisms of $\mathbb C$"? Can there be intermediate cases? Like models where the Galois group of $\mathbb Q$ is abelian, things like that?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I seem to vaguely recall that there was a question whether it is consistent with ZF that Aut($\mathbb C$) has size strictly between $2$ and $2^{2^\omega}$, with inconclusive answers (but I can’t find anything). I believe that at least the Artin–Schreier theorem can be made choiceless enough to show that if there are more than 2 automorphisms, there are infinitely many. However, none of this should concern $\mathrm{Gal}(\tilde{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$, which should be as wild as usual even in ZF, as $\tilde{\mathbb Q}$ is a countable (and therefore well ordered) field.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Did you have in mind [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24047/41291) back from 2010? It currently is on the "Related" list here.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, so automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ need not extend to $\mathbb C$ without choice?  (I know that the standard proofs of extension use choice, but I didn't know if it was essential.)

Comment: @LSpice Indeed, they need not.